# Display tty1 in a terminal window on GUI

Tags: command-line, gui, tty

I am not trying to open a GUI in tty1, but I'm trying to display tty1 in a GUI desktop (Ctrl + Alt + F7).

Because it's running the Daily apt download activities, which prevents me to install anything, and I would like to see both my attempt to install my thing and the Daily apt on the same screen.